# Remove particular character from a string python?

Tags: python, special-characters

I have to remove this:  `®` Character from a string in Python.

Whole string is:

```
'Rainbow® Super Value Construction Paper, 12" x 18", Assorted Colors, Pack Of 100'
```

Comment: Replace it with `''` using `str.replace`.

Comment: What Python version is this? Do you have a unicode or byte string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I used it but getting an error
"Not an ASCII Character"

Comment: @user2357112   

2.7.3

Comment: @DixitSingla Post your code and exact traceback in question body.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method to deal with unwanted characters, but probably

`string.replace('®', '')`

is easier to write.

Comment: I used This method

But getting an error "not an ASCII Character"